# How to properly release ViewControllers after user logout?

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I am trying to build an app supporting user login/logout.

When the app launches I check if user is already logged in, and if so, I will directly segue to the main app, which is a tab bar based view; and if not, I will go to a login view and then perform a segue to main app after user logs in successfully. These work just fine.

The problem is concerning when user logs out. There are two cases when user logs out:

1. If users have already been to the login screen in this time's usage of the app, I can directly perform an unwind segue, and shown by the log I added inside deinit(), all the view controllers in the main app are released from memory.
2. If users have never been to the login screen (which means when they launch the app they are already logged in, so main app shows directly without a login view), here comes the problem: If I directly perform a segue to login screen and the user logs in again, another 'new' main app will be created. Since the 'old' main app views are not released, the 'new' main app view actually doubles the memory. So how can I properly release all the existing main app view controllers after user logs out in this case?

Comment: How do you know you're going to "new" main app view?  And, how is memory actually doubled?  Why aren't you going from login screen back to original main screen?  And have you actually put this under instruments and watched your memory usage and seen where it's all coming from, or are you speculating?

Comment: yep. I keep monitoring the memory usage, and whenever I login again from the login screen, it seems the main app view got created again, and I can see the memory usage increasing as I keep logging out and logging in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the login window you should check how did you arrive there. If login window is the root of your hierarchy, then present main view. If user was logged in and then logged out, then during next login you just hide login window and return to already loaded main view and update its content according new user. This approach do not generates unnecessary main views

Comment: Thank you! It seems a good idea. I'm not sure how exactly I should do it though. I'll start giving it a shot.

Comment: @JayWang you can inspect `presentingViewController` property to figure out if there is some view controller that presented your login view controller